# Как верно указать путь к properties файлу в web проекте?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet, tomcat

Опишу вкратце ситуацию, класс ContextListenner имплементирует ServletContextListener, чтобы вызвать методы из класса ConnectionManager перед инициализацией контекста. Класс ConnectionManager предназначен для создания пула соединений для базы данных. Для инициализации пула я хочу использовать properties файл. Чтобы считать с файла написал следующий метод:

```
public static String getValue(String key) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(new File("D:/Java/Projects/Dictionary/properties/dictionaries.properties")))) {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(br);
        return p.getProperty(key);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Для поиска файла я указываю абсолютный URL, но я понимаю что это не правильно. Проект у меня находится в одной папке, программа eclipse в другой папке, но когда я указываю относительный адрес в методе, он ищет в папке eclipse, а не в папке проекта. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: getClass().getResource("dictionaries.properties") не находит разве?

Comment: Нет, этот метод не пройдет хотя бы потому, что у меня метод статический, а getClass работает только когда создаешь объект.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос с помощью события ServletContextEvent:

```
event.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/dictionaries.properties");
```